# Azure AD redirect URI changes from https to http

Tags: django, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

### Overview

I have an app registered at Azure AD portal. The redirect mechanism has been working great in development, but there is a strange conversion going on Oauth redirect URIs.

Client application is built with Django framework and using MSAL for Python library.

### Problem specifically

Suppose I have redirect URI specified as follows in the Azure AD app registration: `https://myapp.com/auth/redirect`

I get an error `AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '<application ID>'`

Diving into the requests sent, I can see, that the redirect URI gets somehow manipulated somewhere in the process.
(*Note the conversion from **https -> http***)
`...redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%2Fauth%2Fredirect&scope=User.Read.basic....`

But the Azure AD actually doesn't even accept URL's with plain http.

I have tried to produce the same error with just localhost, (since localhost URL is exception to the rule, that only https URL's are allowed) and with redirect URL `http://localhost:8000/auth/redirect` the authentication process works and with `https://localhost:8000/auth/redirect` it produces the same result described above.

Comment: Could you share how do you request your application? What's the reply URL in the request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The actual problem came out was...

The error was related more to Django internals in combination with the MSAL library.

Azure AD [MSAL library for Python](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python) uses `reverse(redirect_uri)` method internally to build the redirect uri somewhere inside and since Django requests use HTTP internally, the redirect uri, that gets added to the request, is the HTTP one.

### Solution

Adding `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` to `settings.py` fixed the problem.

Although the ordinary `./manage.py runserver` command does not support HTTPS, so

1. `pip install werkzeug django-extensions pyOpenSSL`
2. Add `django_extensions` under setting.py `INSTALLED_APPS`
3. Run server with `./manage.py runserver_plus --cert /tmp/cert localhost:8000`

When the program runs in a web server with front proxy, add this line as well, to not change the original request returned by backend:
In settings.py -> `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')`

Answer (score 0):

This error can typically be caused by 2 different configuration issues.

(1) accessing the page from a different address than what you’ve configured for your app.

(2) you have made a mistake in the configuration itself. In both of these cases, it’s typically fairly easy to fix the issue.

It seems the error occurs with the configuration in your issue.

Please notice the `redirect_uri` parameter if requesting `/token` endpoint for access token, the redirect_uri needs to be same as one of the Redirect URIs (navigate to your app -> Authentication) in the portal. If using C#, you also need to set it in the configuration.

[image]

Comment: The redirect address in portal is with HTTPS. It currently seems to me, that the problem lies in wrong configuration on client application side. I am using python Django framework and this library: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python