# Django app with Azure AD account identity provider deployment to Azure Web app service fails

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal

## Background

I am trying to deploy a Django web app with Azure AD as the account identity provider to Azure Web app services following the [Microsoft tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-django-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/sign-in).

My app is registered on the Azure AD portal. It works well in development on `localhost`.

## Problem

However, when i deploy it to Azure Web app services, it fails because it requests a redirect URI starting with **http** while Azure AD requires that any non localhost server must have a redirect URI starting with **https**.
Specifically, it requests a redirect URI as `http://myapp.com/auth/redirect`. But, i am only allowed to register URI `https://myapp.com/auth/redirect` in Azure AD.

This problem was addressed in a related [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66977121/azure-ad-redirect-uri-changes-from-https-to-http)

The solution given was to "Run server with `./manage.py runserver_plus --cert /tmp/cert localhost:8000`".

This works great on `localhost`, but i am having trouble deploying it to Azure web app service.

My deployment file stored in `.github/workflows/deploy_on_<myapp>.yml` has the deploy job defined as follows:

```yaml
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .
          
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'fno-calculator'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_<secret> }}
```

## Questions

- How should i deploy my Django web app with the custom command `./manage.py runserver_plus --cert /tmp/cert localhost:8000` to Azure web app service?
- Is there another way to deploy my Django web app using Azure AD that requests a redirect URI with **https** instead of **http**?

## What i tried

Modified the deployment file to run:

```yaml
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        run: ./manage.py runserver_plus --cert /tmp/cert <servername>:<port_id>
```

## Expected result

Expected the deployment to succeed and the app to be active.

## Actual result

Deployment failed with error `Cannot assign requested address`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a custom startup command is not needed.

It will work simply by following the instructions posted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66977121/azure-ad-redirect-uri-changes-from-https-to-http).

For a production setting, only adding `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` will fix the problem.